# Why Spring filter is always invoked?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm implementing a *REST API* using the *Spring Boot Framework*. I've one public service `/auth/login`

```java
@PostMapping("/auth/login")
fun login(@RequestBody loginRequest: LoginRequest): String {
    val token = tokenProvider.generateToken(loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password)
    if (token === null) {
        throw NotLoggedInError()
    }   
    return token
}
```

It can be used to retrieve a token for secured area `/api/schemas`:

```java
@GetMapping
fun getSchemas() : ArrayList<Schema> = _schemas
```

I've configured my security policies in the `configure(http: HttpSecurity?)` method from my custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` object:

```java
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
    http!!
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
                .and()
            .authenticationProvider(tokenAuth)
                .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).authenticated()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .logout().disable()
}
```

It seems that the `attemptAuthentication` method of the filter is always invoked, even in the case of access of public area.

```java
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
class TokenAuthenticationFilter(requiresAuth: RequestMatcher) : AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter(requiresAuth) {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var tokenAuthenticationProvider: TokenAuthenticationProvider

    private val BEARER = "Bearer"

    override fun attemptAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?): Authentication {
        val param: String? = request!!.getHeader("Authorization")
        val token = removeStart(param!!, BEARER).trim()
        val user = tokenAuthenticationProvider.getUserFromToken(token)
        val auth = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user!!.username, user.password)
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(auth)
    }

    override fun successfulAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, chain: FilterChain?, authResult: Authentication?) {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult)
        chain!!.doFilter(request, response)
    }

    override fun unsuccessfulAuthentication(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, failed: AuthenticationException?) {
        throw NotLoggedInError()
    }
}
```

Any idea ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, Spring Security *always* authenticates a user. In the case authentication is not required (e.g. public endpoints), the user is **still** authenticated as *anonymous*.

In your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(HttpSecurity)`, you explicitly put `restAuthenticationFilter()` *before* `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter::class.java`. This means for Spring Security to authenticate a user as anonymous, it first needs to invoke your filter before it can invoke `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. I have changed the order in the filters replacing the call to addFilterBefore to addFilterAfter, but it still does not work.